# How to mock a method call without actually calling its submethods

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I started using JUnits (Mockito) from yesterday. I searched for similar question, but didn't find.

I have a class with method `method1()` which in turn calls `method2()`.

I don't want to mock `method2`

I am mocking call to `method1()`. I was expecting that it would return the custom object(without going ahead and calling `method2`) which I want. But instead it proceeds and tries to call `method2()`.

```
class A {
    method1() {
    //do something.
    method2();
    }
}
```

I mocked method1 and return any object (say `new Integer(1)`).

I dont want `method2` to be called. but when I am debugging this Junit. It goes and calls `method2`. Hence fails.

Comment: It seams that you are not calling the mock, but the original class. Post your test code so it is possible to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

When using syntax like this:

```
@Test public void yourTest() {
  A mockA = Mockito.mock(A.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
  when(mockA.method1()).thenReturn(Integer.valueOf(1));
}
```

then the first thing Java will do is to evaluate `when(mockA.method1())`, which requires calling `mockA.method1()` to get a value to pass into `when`. You don't notice this with other mocks, because Mockito mocks return nice default values, but with spies and `CALLS_REAL_METHODS` mocks this is a much bigger problem. Clearly, this syntax won't work.

Instead, use the methods beginning with `do`:

```
@Test public void yourTest() {
  A mockA = Mockito.mock(A.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
  doReturn(Integer.valueOf(1)).when(mockA).method1();
}
```

As part of `.when(mockA)`, Mockito will instead return an instance that has no behavior, so the call to `method1()` never happens on a real instance. `do` syntax also works with void methods, which makes it more flexible than `when(...).thenReturn(...)` syntax. Some developers advocate for using `doReturn` all the time; I prefer `thenReturn` because it's slightly easier to read, and can also do return type checking for you.

---

As a side note, prefer `Integer.valueOf(1)` over `new Integer(1)` unless you absolutely need a brand new instance. Java keeps a cache of small integers, and this can be faster than allocating a brand new reference if you need to manually box an `int` into an `Integer`.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you mock interfaces or abstract classes and provide implementations of abstract methods. In your case you want to substitute the real implementation of a concrete class. This can be achieved via partial mocks.

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16